# Show network reputation next to site reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, user-accounts, new-users

I have been around Stack Exchange for a while now and have a decent amount of reputation on some network sites (not crazy much but still a bit). But whenever I sign up for a new network site and thus start up with 101 rep, people feel the need to add a comment welcoming me to the site and often also post a link to the site or network rules.

For an actual new user that seems like a good policy (be nice to them, show them the rules before they do something wrong) but for an old user with a new site account this is somewhere between annoying and a waste of time. Also it is basically comment spam.

So I think it would be good to add network reputation to the user info card so that people reading the post know that they are dealing with an user that might be new to this site but that is experienced with Stack Exchange in general.

Also I think that the "new contributor" tag is not quite fitting for an experienced user.

Comment: This is already done in Area 51; I'd support this request for Meta Stack Exchange as well, but not other sites per the answer.

Comment: In my experience, people usually only post those welcome comments with site information if your question is unclear or off-topic.

Comment: @TheWanderer: I've also had that on rather well-received questions on some networks.

Comment: @Downvoters: Why the downvotes?

Comment: [*On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.*](/help/whats-meta) – which **perfectly** illustrates the point of global reputation not being so important. (I didn't downvote, BTW.)

Answer (score 7):

You might not be a "new contributor" to the network, but some sites have different customs that can take a while to get used to. E.g. [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)'s custom to put answers to questions in spoiler tags; [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)' requirement that a claim you wish to verify to be notable; [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)'s policy to accept only *research-level* mathematics questions, and so on. The 'New contributor' is also shown when you start contributing on a site's meta, regardless of the reputation you have on the main site. [Meta is a different beast](/help/whats-meta); you're illustrating this with a **textbook example** by asking for the reason this question got downvoted. Even users with 100k network reputation sometimes need to learn that

> **On posts tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

The danger of showing the global reputation next to the site reputation will be that other users will think that you'd know a lot about [insert site topic here], because that's one of the things [reputation measures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/295232).

In fact, the 101 reputation combined with the 'New contributor' indicator already implies you have some experience across the network (you earned at least 200 reputation on another site).

Alternatively, consider putting your [flair image](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=flair) on all your profiles across the network. Then it's only one click away for users who really want to know.

Comment: What do you think about making this MSE-only?

Comment: For me personally it isn't necessary; if I see a new face on Meta.SE, I'll check out the network profile. Actually, which sites they come from is at least as important as the combined reputation to me.